# Shortcuts pressing problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

For a long time I was a user of Windows 10, but recently installed second OS - Ubuntu 18.04

For me, the best way to switch language is Ctrl+Shift, so I'd like to stay with it on both systems.

The problem I noticed is that on Windows language switches after shortcut keys are released, while on Ubuntu after shortcut keys are pressed. So when I want to use another shortcut (e.g. anonymous window in chrome - Ctrl+Shift+N) - on Windows it successfully opens, but on Ubuntu - doesn't, because after pressing first two keys of shortcuts it simply changes language

Is there any way to change shortcuts activation behaviour, so it changes language when shortcut is released, but not pressed?

Or maybe there is some other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: See question of which I marked this as a duplicate. It  is a bug that was neversovled up to now. Besides the two answers there, the linked bugreport provides a trick to make i work with a script. I did not test the script, though.